# Busqueda por "external_reference" NO anda

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Estoy teniendo el mismo problema que muchos otros usuarios según he podido leer, la búsqueda por `external_reference` de payments, no funciona.

Supongamos:

```
$filters = array( 
  "external_reference" => 'reterenciaX'
); 

$searchResult = $mp->search_payment($filters,0,10);
```

**Retorna:**

```
array(2) { 
    ["status"]=> int(200), 
    ["response"]=> array(2) { 
        ["paging"]=> array(3) { 
            ["total"]=> int(0),
            ["limit"]=> int(10), 
            ["offset"]=> int(0) 
        },
     ["results"]=> array(0) { } 
   } 
}
```

El external_reference que paso como parámetro estoy 100% seguro que existe, y como se puede ver en el ejemplo estoy pasado explícitamente el `offset` y `limit`, que daba problemas en algunos casos si no se le pasaba al método `search_payment`, pero en este caso, pasándoselo o no, no funciona.

Vale aclarar que los pagos son mediante checkout básico.

¿Alguien ha podido solucionar este problema de alguna forma?

Comment: Una aclaración, estas usando el entorno sandbox o el de producción?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta por parte de Mercado Pago? ¿Cómo hacemos los que ya tenemos `external_reference` con guiones medios?

Comment: Yo estoy en la misma situación, venia funcionando sin problemas y de repente dejo de andar, y si, los ext. ref tienen guiones.

Answer (score 1):

A modo de conocimiento dejo esta respuesta, pude detectar que la búsqueda por external reference no funciona si el external reference tiene "guiones medios" por ejemplo, utilizando un external reference del tipo "XX01", funciona.